# What size image is needed for the Application Image for an Xamarin.Forms application and how and where should I add this?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating an application that I would like to run on Android and iOS devices with different screen sizes.

What size image do I need to use and where should I put this so that it shows as a thumbnail when the application is installed on the device before the application starts to run? In other words the image that a user clicks to start the application.

Also how can I get the best quality image. Should I use a png, jpg or is there another type of image that could be used? Any hints on creating this image would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called App Icon, there are a lot of questions about this on SO and Xamarin docs.

**iOS**

Open `Assets.xcassets` under iOS project

[image]

If there isn't and AppIcon image set created, right click some empty place on the left white area and create a new AppIcon set, then click the AppIcon and just drag and drop the differents images size (you can see all the sizes the app need)

[image]

Finally open the Info.plist file and choose AppIcon as Source for App Icons

[image]

That should be enough for iOS App Icon, you can check this for more info: [Application Icons in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=vsmac)

**Android**

For Android you would need to create icons with different sizes:

```
hdpi=281*164
mdpi=188*110
xhdpi=375*219
xxhdpi=563*329
xxxhdpi=750*438

48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)
```

Then check if under `Resources` folder on the Android project are some folders named `mipmap-(size)`, if not create like below:

[image]

Then place the icons in the corresponding folder with their size.
Next you want to do is set the icon on the Android Manifest, so right click on the Android project and open Properties, then on Android Manifest tab (VS for Windows) or Android Application (VS for Mac) choose your icon, so it should look like `@mipmap/MyIcon` and on your Main Launcher Activity set the icon like `Icon = "@mipmap/MyIcon"`.

All images should be png type.

Comment: Can you explain more about the Android sizes. I read what you said here "For Android you would need to create icons with different sizes .. " but the table you show doesn't make any sense to me :-(

Comment: @Alan2 on the table the first group are the sizes for the drawable images and second groud for mipmap icons sizes, so you must create your icon with all the sizes for mipmap, e.g.: for mipmap-hdpi your icon size must be 72x72, for mipmap-xxhdpi must be 144x144

Comment: @FabriBertani Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Update: I believe correct folder names are now drawable-(size). I.e. "drawable-xxhdpi"